# Websocket -> StreamingResponse -> Chart.JS

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am trying to follow this guide:
https://ron.sh/creating-real-time-charts-with-fastapi/

I have created a websocket that sends data back and forth from a raspberry pi to my Heroku Server. I've been stuck trying to modify the above code to await a yielded json from the websocket.receive() and pass it to the /chart_data endpoint. So far, I'm able to get the client and server to ping-pong the data I want and a "message received" response.

```
@application.websocket("/ws")
async def generate_random_data(websocket: WebSocket) -> Iterator[str]:

await websocket.accept()

client_ip = websocket.headers

logger.info("Client %s connected", client_ip)

def yieldy(ws_msg):
    msg = json.loads(received["text"])
    data = msg["temperature"]
    logger.info("in-loop", msg)  
    json_data = json.dumps(
        {
            "time": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            "value": data,
        }
    )
    yield json_data

   
while True:
    try:
        received= await websocket.receive()
        logger.info(received)
        
        for value in yieldy(received["text"]):
            print(value)

        await websocket.send_text('data received')

    except Exception as e:
        
        print(f"Terminated")
        print(e)
        break

    

    greeting = "Data received! "
    await websocket.send_text(greeting)
```

How do I use the json_data object in something like this:

```
@application.get("/chart-data")
async def chart_data(request: Request) -> StreamingResponse:
    response = StreamingResponse(generate_random_data(request), media_type="text/event-stream")
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
    return response
```

losing lots of sleep - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don’t think you understand fully what role each component plays in your design. A web socket endpoint can’t forward a request to another endpoint like that

Comment: @JarroVGIT I understand that part. I want to know how to take the JSON payload and pass it to the other FastAPI endpoint to plot the data. 

In the meantime I'm reading up on async await and yield to learn how I can refer to realtime data outside of the websocket function